# How to redirect all the http requests to https on zPanel

Tags: redirect, ssl, https, http-status-code-301

I've configured a domain using a Positive SSL certificate. My dedicated server runs on CentOS 6 with Apache and zPanel.

I want to redirect all the http pages to https.

I've tried a lot of different codes on .htaccess but none works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

It looks like it ignores my .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if your Apache server has mod_rewrite enabled.
If you have zpanel all set up just login as an admin and go to "Admin > phpinfo > view full php configuration". On the newly opened page scroll down to "apache2handler" and check your mod_ modules.

Ensure your .htaccess is in your web root directory eg. "public_html" nad chmoded to 644.